Google devtools not working with --remote-debugging-port
titles says it all, i cant get it to work, i launched with parameters "chrome.exe --remote-debugging-port=9999" and am attempting to send a websocket request via boost asio in c++, whenever i attempt to access localhost:9999/devtools it also comes up with "localhost was unable to load this page".
test code was generated using AI:
#include <iostream>
#include <websocketpp/config/asio_no_tls_client.hpp>
#include <websocketpp/client.hpp>
#include <nlohmann/json.hpp>

using json = nlohmann::json;
typedef websocketpp::client<websocketpp::config::asio_client> client;

client c; // Global client instance

void on_open(websocketpp::connection_hdl hdl) {
    std::cout << "Connection opened!" << std::endl;

    // Prepare JSON payload for navigation command
    json payload = {
        {"id", 1},
        {"method", "Page.navigate"},
        {"params", {{"url", "http://example.com"}}}
    };

    // Convert JSON payload to string
    std::string message = payload.dump();

    // Send the command
    c.send(hdl, message, websocketpp::frame::opcode::text);
}

void on_message(websocketpp::connection_hdl hdl, client::message_ptr msg) {
    std::cout << "Received message: " << msg->get_payload() << std::endl;
}

void on_close(websocketpp::connection_hdl hdl) {
    std::cout << "Connection closed!" << std::endl;
}

int main() {
    // Initialize ASIO
    c.init_asio();

    // Set handlers
    c.set_open_handler(&on_open);
    c.set_message_handler(&on_message);
    c.set_close_handler(&on_close);

    // Get the correct WebSocket URL from http://localhost:9999/json
    std::string uri = "ws://127.0.0.1:9999/json"; // Replace with actual WebSocket URL from JSON response
    websocketpp::lib::error_code ec;

    client::connection_ptr con = c.get_connection(uri, ec);

    if (ec) {
        std::cout << "Could not create connection because: " << ec.message() << std::endl;
        return 0;
    }

    // Connect and start the ASIO io_service run loop
    c.connect(con);

    try {
        c.run();
    }
    catch (const std::exception& e) {
        std::cout << e.what() << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}

ADDITIONAL ERRORS:
[2024-11-20 07:45:07] [connect] Successful connection
[2024-11-20 07:45:07] [error] Server handshake response error: websocketpp.processor:20 (Invalid HTTP status.)
[2024-11-20 07:45:07] [fail] WebSocket Connection 127.0.0.1:6969 - "WebSocket++/0.8.2" /json 404 websocketpp.processor:20 Invalid HTTP status.

Please see the FAQ on how to ask good questions. Here's what I previously made in this area with Beast: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70768742/chrome-devtools-protocol-using-boost-beast/70777042#70777042 - perhaps reading it will give you an idea of where to look/how to proceed

Using this code against
chromium-brower --remote-debuging-port=6969

Shows:

The weird part is /json in your question. It is probably what leads to HTTP 404 error.

Wow. Did someone actually downvote this? That's really quite harsh. Why would people even spend the effort anymore. I'm guessing people just /do not/ appreciate how much effort is involved in installing websocketpp, nlohmann, chromium-browser, configuring the project, making it compile, then testing it. Sigh.

It's likely for the text in the picture. I agree with the downvote because the drawn text in the picture on my mobile screen has the height ~0.5 mm and is horrible.

@3CxEZiVlQ It's just that it contains text that cannot be copy pasted. Oh well. I thought downvotes signify "this answer isn't useful", not "there's things I don't like/not ordinarily desired". Besides edits exist. One of those days I guess.
